# column to row for only one column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have only one column in my table having all distinct values I need to group it into pairs of 3 and make  3 columns out of 3 rows please help

Source

```
COL1
-----
A
B
C
D
E
F
```

Required output 1:

```
COL1
------
A,B,C
D,E,F
```

Required output 2:

```
col1  col2  col3
----  ----  ----
A     B     C
D     E     F
```

Comment: Which Oracle version are you using? (Output 1 is very easy with 11.2, much harder with previous versions)

Comment: what about if table has only five rows?
means A,B,C,D and E?

Comment: no this will not be the case for sure

Answer (score 1):

Output 1:

```
select listagg(col1, ',') within group (order by col1) as col
from (
  select col1,
         case 
           when row_number() over (order by col1) <= (count(*) over ()) / 2 then 0
           else 1
         end as grp
  from foo
)
group by grp
order by grp;
```

For Output 2:

```
select max(col1) as col1,
       max(col2) as col2, 
       max(col3) as col3
from (
  select case mod(row_number() over (order by col1),3)
            when 1 then col1
            else null
         end as col1,
         case mod(row_number() over (order by col1),3)
            when 2 then col1
            else null
         end as col2,         
         case mod(row_number() over (order by col1),3)
            when 0 then col1
            else null
         end as col3,
         case 
           when row_number() over (order by col1) <= (count(*) over ()) / 2 then 0
           else 1
         end as grp
  from foo
)
group by grp
order by grp;
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d699c/1

Comment: Thanks mate, can output 2 be generalized?

Comment: @user2698972: the number of columns must be hardcoded by the number of case statements (at least I don't see a better way). The number of rows can be "generalized" by adjusting the comparison for the `grp` column

Answer (score 1):

Please try below query for second solution:

```
select Col1, Col2, Col3 From(
  select 
    ceil(row_number() over(order by Col1)/3) Rnum, 
    mod(row_number() over(order by Col1)+2, 3)+1 Row_Num, 
    COl1 
  from 
    YourTable
)x pivot (min(Col1) for Row_Num in ('1' as Col1, '2'  as Col2, '3'  as Col3));
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/72e1a/1)

Answer (score 0):

Another way (will work for every multiple of 3 of records)

output1

```
select listagg(col1, ',') within group (order by col1) col1
from
(select col1, row_number() over(order by col1) rn
from t) tt
group by rn - decode(mod (rn, 3) ,0,3,mod (rn, 3));
```

output2

```
select c2_col col1, c3_col col2, c1_col col3 
from
(select rn - decode(mod (rn, 3) ,0,3,mod (rn, 3)) grp, mod(rn, 3) rnm, col1
 from
(select col1, row_number() over(order by col1) rn
from t)) tt
pivot
(
  max(col1) as col
  for rnm in (0 as c1,1 c2,2 c3)
  );
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/71328/27)